# How can i change color of button in android studio

Tags: android-studio

i want to change background color of button to black

this is my code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!--    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/relayoutid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id_button"
            android:text="xem thời gian"

            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_textview"
            android:text="Hello World!"

            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but even i use

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

it still change to violet (it happen even i choose other color).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaJwW.png)

can any help me to change background color of button. Thanks for reading and i'm so sorry bc my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

app:iconTint="@color/LaranjaGiassi"/>
go into res (resources) then values than colors, add a color there like this
#FA9850
then in your button
app:iconTint="@color/LaranjaGiassi"/>

Comment: I did it your way. But it still doesn't change

Comment: i can change color of text, but with background color i can't

Comment: https://youtu.be/AdlxIdYus14 android studio also uses themes to set color so if you want an app to have an overall theme change the colors from the theme file itself, also there is a day and night theme but you can disable whichever one you one with
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

at the startup java file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).